# Getting an inf result in console after for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am getting an inf result after using the test case in the problem

```
balance = 42
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04
def AfterBalance(balance,annualInterestRate,monthlyPaymentRate):
  monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
for i in range(12):
    monthlyPaymentRate = monthlyPaymentRate * balance
    monthlyUnpaid = balance - monthlyPaymentRate
    balance = monthlyUnpaid + monthlyInterestRate * monthlyUnpaid
  return round(balance,2)
LastBalance = AfterBalance(balance,annualInterestRate,monthlyPaymentRate)
print("Remaining balance", LastBalance)
```

I expected the case to result to 31.38
I just need to know how the inf result was formed.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't mean to actually write `monthlyPaymentRate = monthlyPaymentRate * balance`... You are reusing the same variable name for two different things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calculating the payment based on the original balance, you're recalculating it based on the updated balance in each iteration, which leads to an incorrect computation.

Consequently, the `monthlyPaymentRate` grows exponentially large with each iteration, eventually causing the subsequent calculation of `monthlyUnpaid` and balance to yield 'inf' (infinity) due to division by zero or very close to zero.

To fix this issue, you should keep track of the original balance and use it to compute the monthly payment in each iteration.

```
balance = 42
annualInterestRate = 0.2
monthlyPaymentRate = 0.04

def AfterBalance(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyPaymentRate):
    monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
    for i in range(12):
        monthlyPayment = monthlyPaymentRate * balance
        monthlyUnpaid = balance - monthlyPayment
        balance = monthlyUnpaid + monthlyInterestRate * monthlyUnpaid
    return round(balance, 2)

LastBalance = AfterBalance(balance, annualInterestRate, monthlyPaymentRate)
print("Remaining balance", LastBalance)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Remaining balance 31.38
```